# How are proper tail calls enabled in ES5/strict mode?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, strict, ecmascript-harmony, tail-call-optimization

Today, I was reading the [harmony:proper_tail_calls](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proper_tail_calls) proposal and I noticed that in the [references](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proper_tail_calls#references) there was a link which read, “[Brendan discovers that ES5/strict enables TCO.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=445363#c20)”

What does it mean that ES5/strict “enables” TCO? At first I thought that initial implementations of proper tail calls were available in ES5/strict mode. However, that is clearly not the case as demonstrated by these benchmarks:

1. [ES5/strict TCO](http://jsperf.com/es5-strict-tco) (n = 10000).
2. [ES5/strict TCO](http://jsperf.com/es5-strict-tco/2) (n = 1000).

I used the following two functions in the above benchmarks:

```js
function without_tco(x) {
    if (x === 0) return x;
    return without_tco(x - 1);
}

function with_tco(x) {
    "use strict";
    if (x === 0) return x;
    return with_tco(x - 1);
}
```

Anyway, my question is: how are proper tail calls “enabled” in ES5/strict mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that strict mode makes calls in proper tail position guaranteed to be able to be implemented as tail calls, since it prohibits anything that might interfere with that optimization; namely that a strict-mode function cannot be accessed through a `caller` property. It doesn’t mean “enables” in the sense that Firefox implemented it already.